# How to specify popup display mode in DotNetOpenAuth for Google OpenId provider?

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I have an ASP.NET application that uses DotNetOpenAuth 3.5 for Google OpenId authentication.

I recently had to change the OpenId behaviour to a window popup for smoother UX experience. However, the popup window displays a dialog for Google login that is not optimized for a popup  window. I realized I have to somehow add the ltmpl=popup parameter to the url https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?, but have not idea how. Could you offer some help? This is the code I am using

```
string discoveryUri = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id";
OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
var b = new UriBuilder(context.Request.Url);
var req = openid.CreateRequest(discoveryUri, b.Uri, b.Uri);
var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
req.AddExtension(fetchRequest);
req.RedirectToProvider();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard of this `ltmpl=popup` parameter that you mention, but there is an OpenID UI extension that is supposed to be how the RP communicates to the OP that it is in a popup window. I've added the necessary line to your code snippet, and cleaned up some other bits as well.

```
var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
var req = openid.CreateRequest(WellKnownProviders.Google);
var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
req.AddExtension(fetchRequest);
req.AddExtension(new UIRequest()); // inform the OP it's in a popup.
req.RedirectToProvider();
```

The UIRequest extension adds a `openid.ui.mode=popup` parameter to the authentication request.